# How to identify the formula for calculating Cohen's d?

Tags: self-study

If I am just asked to calculate Cohen's d what do I do?
Do I take the sample mean from the population mean and then divide that by the sample std deviation?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_size#Cohen.27s_d.

Answer (score 2):

The denominator for Cohen's *d* isn't just one sample's standard deviation, unless that's all you have. What data do you have? It sounds like a one-sample problem where you're given both a sample mean $\bar x$ and the population mean $\mu$, and asked to calculate the effect size of the difference.

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_size#Cohen.27s_d):

> What precisely the standard deviation *s* is was not originally made explicit by [Jacob Cohen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_Cohen_%28statistician%29) because he defined it (using the symbol "σ") as "the standard deviation of either population (since they are assumed equal)".<sup>[7]</sup>
>   Other authors make the computation of the standard deviation more explicit with the following definition for a [pooled standard deviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pooled_standard_deviation)<sup>[16]</sup> with two independent samples.
>   $$s = \sqrt{\frac{(n_1-1)s^2_1 + (n_2-1)s^2_2}{n_1+n_2-2}}\\s_1^2 = \frac{1}{n_1-1} \sum_{i=1}^{n_1} (x_{1,i} - \bar{x}_1)^2$$

So again, think about what descriptive statistics you already have. If you have sample means and *SD*s for two samples, this ought to be pretty straightforward for you (and you should explain what you've tried so far). If not, do you have a population standard deviation (denoted as $\sigma$)? It sounds like you have a sample standard deviation at least...If that's all you have to work with, I guess that wouldn't leave you with much choice.

On the other hand, if you have a choice between a population *SD* parameter and a sample *SD* statistic, do you think it would do any good to pool these? Can you see why it might make sense to just assume one standard deviation is equal to the other? Which one makes more sense to use this way?

---

> <sup>**References**
>
>   7. [Cohen, J.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacob_Cohen_%28statistician%29) (1988). *Statistical power analysis for the behavioral sciences* (2nd ed.). [Lawrence Erlbaum Associates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lawrence_Erlbaum_Associates).
>
>   16. Hartung, J., Knapp, G., & Sinha, B. K. (2008). *Statistical meta-analysis with application*. Hoboken, NJ: [Wiley](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Wiley_%26_Sons).</sup>